# Copying Excel Cell and retaining Line Breaks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am generating a HTML email template using Excel to save time.

Essentially B2 contains the Header
eg

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
```

B3 contains various sections that are populated using excel cell data
EG

```
<tags>stuff</tags>
<tags>stuff</tags>
```

B4 also contains a section of html populated using excel data

B5 contains the footer.
eg

```
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

B6 then creates the full html document using the formula =B2&B3&B4&B5

Now if I copy the cell B5 and paste into notepad, it will strip the line breaks and look something like this:

```
</table</body></html>
```

I can keep the linebreaks intact by double clicking this cell and copying the data.

However, because B6 contains a formula, i cannot double click on this cell to copy the data as it will revert to the formula. If I copy the entire cell, all linebreaks are removed.

eg

```
<html><head></head><body><table><tags>stuff</tags><tags>stuff</tags></table</body></html>
```

So the question is, how can I copy cell B6 while retaining all line breaks?

Cheers

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan--looks like you answered your own question (and mine!). I'll add it here, for others with the same question.

To get the line breaks in Excel to appear in Notepad (or other plain text form):

1. Modify your equation to include appropriate linebreak characters using Excel's CHAR() function. Windows: CHAR(10). Mac: CHAR(13). E.g. set Cell B6 to:

   ```
   =B2 & CHAR(10) & B3 & CHAR(10) & B4 & CHAR(10) & B5
   ```
2. Copy results form cell B6 and paste in Microsoft Word
3. Copy resulting text from Microsoft Word into Notepad (or other plain text destination)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to provide an example of what exactly are you doing, but some thoughs about line break in Excel:

- In order to preserve a line break through formula, Alt-Enter doesn't always work. You need to use CHAR function to insert a line break (CHAR(10) in Windows/Wine, CHAR(13) in MacOS). A REPLACE function here could help you to "fix" your line breaks.
- To proper display a line break in a cell, the "Wrap Text" option must be enable on that cell. This also means if you don't enable "Wrap Text" before copying, the copy will follow without the break lines sometimes (it depends on Excel version and Operating System, though).
- If you're copying from one cell to another, both cells should have the "Wrap Text" option enabled for expected behaviour.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Fernando, sorry I did not describe my issue properly for you. I have adjusted the question hopefully it makes more sense. Essentially I am trying to copy data from a cell into notepad while keeping the linebreaks intact.

Comment: No problem at all, Ryan. Are you using the CHAR function as I've mentioned? I'm on a MacOS (Excel 2004), and following the both conditions (CHAR instead of Alt-Enter, Wrap Text option turned on at B6) I'm copying it to a plain text editor and it behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, I also tried the Char Function however it had the same result. Good news is that I have now found a workable solution (both with alt + enter and char(10). You can paste the cell into word as this will retain the line breaks, then copy this into notepad. Thanks for your help